# How BuildLabel property generated?

Tags: java, ant, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I'm working on some maven project in eclipse, and using Jazz source control.
I made few build definitions , which run Ant script(build.xml).[like this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_9.5.0/com.ibm.rational.llc.ui.doc/topics/t_cc_rtc_ext_builddef.html).

I've noticed that my build label('buildLabel' property - which consider built-in property - [look here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSJJ9R_5.0.1/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/r_buildprop.html)) is like yyyymmdd-nnnn. Where nnnn seems to be a number that look like the current time in the build machine.
regarding of that, I have few questions:
1) when this property first generated?
2) which timezone had been used there?
3) and from where exacly this timezone fetched?(any env variable?)
4) how can I change this time zone ? ( I mean, when this property first generating)

Thanks!

**UPDATE #1**:
Meanwhile I managed to find a work-around for changing the time zone(with my ant script).
First, I created new property with the UTC timezone:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="buildLabelNewTime" pattern="yyyyMMdd-hhmm" timezone="UTC"/>
</tstamp>
```

After that, I created new target to change the build label:

```
<target name="changeLabel" description="Change build label">
    <buildResultPublisher repositoryAddress="${repositoryAddress}" userId="${USER_ID}" passwordFile="${PASSWORD_FILE}" buildResultUUID="${buildResultUUID}" label="${buildLabelNewTime}" />
</target>
```

Hope it'll help someone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BuilDLabel in RTC is generated by the Jazz Build Engine and at this moment (RTC 6.0.6) it cannot be changed.

There is an open request for enhancement in IBM for that

[Support property to specify build label format](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=113599)

As far as I BuildLabel is generated using timezone in which RTC Server is working.

Comment: Thanks!  too bad it can't be enhanced.. :/